# Date formats .NET to mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date, datetime

I'm pulling date values out of mysql and displaying them in locally used format. See below:

I have this datetime value `2012-11-01 08:00:00` ... yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

I need this to appear as `01-11-2012 08:00:00` ... dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss

I can do this simply enough as follows:

```
Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(sql)

If dr.Read()
    Dim mydate As DateTime = dr("date_column")

    txtDate.Text = mydate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") & " " & mydate.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
End If
```

This works well enough, but my problem is that if I want to update the record from this textbox, I can't use this format for the date because mysql complains about an error (object out of range or something).

So what I need to do now is to convert this back to yyyy-MM-dd. The difficulty here is that .NET will automatically assume my `dd` value should be the `MM` value and vice versa.

This results in a value of `01-11-2012` writing into the database as `11-01-2012`.

How can I reformat the date for insert/update into the database while maintaining the integrity of the date that's being used here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a note, you don't need the string concatenation when displaying the date.  You can just use mydate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") to get your desired format without a second call to ToString.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [parameterized](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries) [query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) for the update:

```
query = "UPDATE SomeTable SET date_column = @newDate WHERE record_id = @record_id"
conn = new SqlConnection("my connection string")

cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("newDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = new Date(txtDate.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("record_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = record_id

'Rest of code to execute cmd
```

If that doesn't parse the date from the TextBox correct, parse it beforehand with:

```
Date.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Also, the line:

```
txtDate.Text = mydate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") & " " & mydate.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```

could also be written as:

```
txtDate.Text = mydate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

which might be easier to read.

Comment: Thank you sir, you caught the problem I had with the iFormatProvider parameter :) How to choose an answer though...

Comment: lol I know how to do it... but your answer and JMK's answer are both almost exactly the same. Yours involves a clear indication of best practice though

Comment: I would say best practice dictates keeping the date in a DateTime variable so you can avoid doing the parsing in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Use `DateTime.Parse` to convert your new string back into a Date object, and then you can insert back into MySQL using `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")`

You can also use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) to create a date object, and specify exactly how the date object is formatted in the string like so:

```
Imports System.Globalization

Dim myNewDate As DateTime
myNewDate = DateTime.ParseExact("23-05-2012 15:45:35", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

//InsertIntoMySQL is whetever method you use to insert into MySQL
InsertIntoMySQL("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'ParseExact' accepts this number of arguments

Answer (score 2):

Try converting the text in the textbox to DateTime type and then format that as MySql standard. Then use that string in your insert and update statements.

```
Convert.ToDateTime(textBox.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```